# InputLayer doesn't show up in clone_function when cloning model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Hi I have a simple neural network with this structure

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(1, 20)]                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (1, 20)                  420  
                                                                 
 predictions (Activation)    (1, 20)                  0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

This is the code for my network

```
input = layers.Input(batch_shape=(1, 20))
x = layers.Dense(20)(input)
output = layers.Activation(name="predictions", activation="softmax")(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

I want to clone the model and modify the layers using this:

```
def custom_clone_function(layer):
    print("layer:", layer)
    return layer

cloned_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(
    model,
    clone_function=custom_clone_function,
)
```

**Input layer is missing from output**

```
layer: <keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x17ce3b580>
layer: <keras.layers.core.activation.Activation object at 0x17ce3a6b0>
```

How can I modify my network so the input layer shows up

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the doc, the input layer is not pass to the clone_function

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/clone_model#args

> Callable to be used to clone each layer in the target model (except InputLayer instances).

So changing the network will not help, maybe there is a workaround, you  should open a question with your final need